# Javascript function in loop not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some html code

```
<table class="layout" border="0" width="90%" align="center">

<form name="addcust" action="insrtCustomer.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateall(this);">

    <td colspan="2">

    <table border="0" width="70%" align="center">

<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2">

    <div class="heading2">Infy Bank</div>

    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2"><p class="heading3">Add New Customer</p></td>

</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>

<!--comments: To display customer name field-->

<tr>
    <td>Customer Name<span class="mandatory">*</span></td><td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="25" onKeyUp="validatecustomername();" onBlur="validatecustomername();"><label id="message"></label></td>

</tr>

<!--comments: To display customer gender field-->

<tr>
    <td>Gender<span class="mandatory">*</span></td><td>
    <input type ="radio" name ="rad1" value="1" checked>male
    <input type ="radio" name ="rad1" value="1">female
    </td>
</tr>

<!--comments: To display customer date of birth field-->

<tr>
        <td>Date of Birth <span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
        <td> <select name ="day">
        <option value ="1">1</option>
        <option value ="2">2</option>
        <option value ="3">3</option>
        <option value ="4">4</option>
        <option value ="5">5</option>
        <option value ="6">6</option>
        <option value ="7">7</option>
        <option value ="8">8</option>
        <option value ="9">9</option>
        <option value ="10">10</option>
        <option value ="11">11</option>
        <option value ="12">12</option>
        <option value ="13">13</option>
        <option value ="14">14</option>
        <option value ="15">15</option>
        <option value ="16">16</option>
        <option value ="17">17</option>
        <option value ="18">18</option>
        <option value ="19">19</option>
        <option value ="20">20</option>
        <option value ="21">21</option>
        <option value ="22">22</option>
        <option value ="23">23</option>
        <option value ="24">24</option>
        <option value ="25">25</option>
        <option value ="26">26</option>
        <option value ="27">27</option>
        <option value ="28">28</option>
        <option value ="29">29</option>
        <option value ="30">30</option>
        <option value ="31">31</option>
        </select>
        <select name ="month">
        <option value ="1">JAN</option>
        <option value ="2">FEB</option>
        <option value ="3">MAR</option>
        <option value ="4">APR</option>
        <option value ="5">MAY</option>
        <option value ="6">JUN</option>
        <option value ="7">JUL</option>
        <option value ="8">AUG</option>
        <option value ="9">SEP</option>
        <option value ="10">OCT</option>
        <option value ="11">NOV</option>
        <option value ="12">DEC</option>
        </select>
        <select name ="year">
        <option value ="1950">1950</option>
                <option value ="1951">1951</option>
                <option value ="1952">1952</option>
                <option value ="1953">1953</option>
                <option value ="1954">1954</option>
                <option value ="1955">1955</option>
                <option value ="1956">1956</option>
                <option value ="1957">1957</option>
                <option value ="1958">1958</option>
                <option value ="1959">1959</option>
                <option value ="1960">1960</option>
                <option value ="1961">1961</option>
                <option value ="1962">1962</option>
                <option value ="1963">1963</option>
                <option value ="1964">1964</option>
                <option value ="1965">1965</option>
                <option value ="1966">1966</option>
                <option value ="1967">1967</option>
                <option value ="1968">1968</option>
                <option value ="1969">1969</option>
                <option value ="1970">1970</option>
                <option value ="1971">1971</option>
                <option value ="1972">1972</option>
                <option value ="1973">1973</option>
                <option value ="1974">1974</option>
                <option value ="1975">1975</option>
                <option value ="1976">1976</option>
                <option value ="1977">1977</option>
                <option value ="1978">1978</option>
        <option value ="1979">1979</option>
        <option value ="1980">1980</option>
        <option value ="1981">1981</option>
        <option value ="1982">1982</option>
        <option value ="1983">1983</option>
        <option value ="1984">1984</option>
        <option value ="1985">1985</option>
        <option value ="1986">1986</option>
        <option value ="1987">1987</option>
        <option value ="1988">1988</option>
        <option value ="1989">1989</option>
        <option value ="1990">1990</option>
        </select>
        </td>
</tr>

<!--comments: To display customer address field-->

<tr>
    <td>Address<span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
    <td>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="addr" maxlength="50"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>City<span class="mandatory">*</span></td><td><input type="text" name="city" maxlength="25" onKeyUp="validateCity();" onBlur="validateCity();"><label id="message4"></label></td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>State<span class="mandatory">*</span></td><td><input type="text" name="state" maxlength="25" onKeyUp="validateState();" onBlur="validateState();"><label id="message5"></label></td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>PIN<span class="mandatory">*</span></td><td><input type="text" name="pinno" maxlength="6" onKeyUp="validatePIN();" onBlur="validatePIN();"><label id="message6"></label></td>
</tr>

<!--comments: To display customer telephone number field-->

<tr>
    <td>Telephone Number<span></span></td><td><input type="text" name="telephoneno" maxlength="15" onKeyUp="validateTelephone();" onBlur="validateTelephone();"><label id="message7"></label></td>
</tr>

<!--comments: To display customer email id field-->

<tr>
    <td>E-mail<span class="mandatory">*</span></td><td><input type="text" name="emailid" maxlength="30" onKeyUp="validateEmail();" onBlur="validateEmail();"><label id="message9"></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>User Id<span class="mandatory">*</span></td><td><input type="text" name="uid" maxlength="30" onKeyUp="validateuserid();" onBlur="validateuserid();"><label id="message23"></label></td>
</tr>

<!--comments: To display submit and reset buttons-->
<tr>
        <td><span class="mandatory">*<font size="3"><b> mandatory fields</b></font></span></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub"/>
        <input type ="reset" value ="Reset" name ="res"></td>
</tr>

</form>

</table>
```

i have write a code in javascript function for all fields. If all fields are empty then i have do alert for that. but all time that alert is appear.

Here is the javascript code

```
function validateall(dis)
{
 var lbl=document.getElementsByTagName('label');
 var imax=7;
 for(var i=0;i<=imax;i++)
 {
  //var j=i-1;
  var v=lbl[i].getAttribute("id");
  var x=document.getElementById(v).style.visibility;
  if(x=="hidden" && i==lbl.length)
  {
   return true;
  }
  else{
   alert("please fill * fields");
   return false;
  }
 }
}
```

here please check my javacript code and giver me suggestions where i am wrong.

if all fields are empty then also alert is appear. please help.

Comment: what do you mean by this - but all time that alert is appear.

Comment: If the for loops ends you can say if i < imax then also loop continously displays the result.

Comment: Why do you need to get the ID attribute? You have the element in `lbl[i]`, you don't need to look it up by ID.

Comment: Where in your Javascript do you check whether fields are empty?

Comment: The function returns from i=0 as you have return in both if and else conditions. Also why are you checking the labels? I think what you need is text boxes and not labels.

Comment: Instead of checking if style is visible or not why dont you check if label field is empty or not. In that way you can assure that if there is any error then the desired fields will not be empty and if there is no error then label field be empty..

Comment: you always `return` on the first run of the loop, so you never even check the other elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the

```
x=="hidden" condition.
```

The

```
var x = document.getElementById(v).style.visibility;
```

always returns `x` to `""` because you have not set the visibility of `labels` to hidden.

So the `if (x == "hidden" && i == lbl.length)` condition fails and always goes to the else block.

Comment: It would be nice if somebody can tell the reason of downvoting.

Comment: ya you r right that by default x=null.but we have set this to hidden you can check here all my code in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/VLkEv/